# Unable to open service url from minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I have a service running on minikube which as you can see from screenshots is accessible when I ssh to minikube but when I try to access it through browser on PC where minikube is running then it is not accessible. Can you please help me find the problem.

[image: Service]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I used port-forward and that worked.

```
kubectl port-forward service/frontend -n guestbook-qa 8080:80
```

[image]